# Slow MySQL SELECT performance

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following database schema:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/37915176/schema.PNG

I have more than 2 millions records in meter_relevation. The data is coming from several electrical meters which are associated to appliances (devices) with the meter_history table.

I try to get the data of a device for a specific date range:

```
SELECT MR.* 
FROM device AS D, meter_history AS MH, meter AS M, meter_relevation AS MR
WHERE D.Id=MH.Id_Device 
   AND MH.Id_Meter=M.Id 
   AND M.Id=MR.Id_Meter 
   AND D.Id="8" 
   AND MR.Date>="2012-10-04" 
   AND MR.Date<="2012-10-04"
```

But the performance are very slow, I can get 10 seconds even if there are no record for the specified date range.

I tried EXPLAIN and I clearly see that my query is not optimal, on the meter_relevation table is listing the total number of rows, more than 2 millions: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/37915176/explain.png

Any suggestions? There is a better way? Of course I could do some work on the client side and split in several queries. But I would like to know if there are better way for a single SELECT query.

Comment: Please post the output of EXPLAIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is the query you're running, it looks sub-optimal. You don't really need the D table, or do you? Seeing as how the condition on device could be satisfied by `MH.Id_device = "8"`.

But supposing there are other fields which aren't shown, then let's rewrite:

```
SELECT MR.*
    FROM meter_relevation AS MR
    JOIN meter AS M ON ( M.Id = MR.ID_Meter )
    JOIN meter_history AS MH ON ( MH.Id_Meter = M.Id )
    JOIN device AS D ON ( D.Id=MH.Id_Device AND D.Id = "8" )
WHERE 
    MR.Date BETWEEN "2012-10-04" AND "2012-10-04";
```

So we need indexes. The first is the most important

```
CREATE INDEX mr_ndx     ON meter_relevation ( Date, Id_Meter );
```

But try also deleting the index above and using instead:

```
CREATE INDEX mr_ndx     ON meter_relevation ( Id_Meter, Date );


CREATE INDEX m_ndx      ON meter(Id); -- This probably already exists
CREATE INDEX mh_ndx     ON meter_history( Id_Device, Id_Meter );
CREATE INDEX d_ndx      ON device (Id); -- This too probably already exists
```

The above, if written just like that, is equivalent (but MySQL should realize this, so I don't think it's slowing you too much) to

```
SELECT MR.*
    FROM meter_relevation AS MR
    JOIN meter AS M ON ( MR.ID_Meter = M.Id)
    JOIN meter_history AS MH ON (MH.Id_Device = "8" AND MH.Id_Meter = M.Id)
WHERE 
    MR.Date BETWEEN "2012-10-04" AND "2012-10-04";
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. I'm definitely a newbie. I'm creating right now the index (it take a little bit of time). As soon I have the index on MR.Date I'll try your queries. Thank you again!

Comment: And yes, I don't really need the D table :-)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you try putting indexes on columns:

```
D.Id
MH.Id_Device 
MH.Id_Meter
M.Id 
MR.Id_Meter 
MR.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's doing a table scan because of missing indexes. Try commenting out this bit and see if it improves:

```
AND MR.Date>="2012-10-04" 
AND MR.Date<="2012-10-04"
```

If so, then try an index on MR.Date.

Comment: You are right, without the WHERE in Date it's vey fast. I definetely need an index on MR.Date. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Indexing will certainly help. Run an EXPLAIN and index appropriately. Index all your foreign keys and the date field. Here's more detail on indexing for JOINs.

http://hackmysql.com/case4

Generally the simplest solution is to avoid overly complex queries. You're joining 4 tables. Do you really need all the data from all 4 tables? I usually avoid SELECT * queries to force myself to ensure I'm only fetching the data I need.